# Retrieve/Deploy a custom metadata type's list view?

Tags: metadata-api, list-view, migration-tool, custom-metadata, package.xml

I'm trying to deploy a list view for a custom metadata type using the Force.com Migration Tool, but I am unable to locate the ListView to include in my package.xml retrieve.  I have deployed many ListViews for custom objects, but ListViews for custom metadata types aren't showing up in the "metadata explorer" interface I use (Workbench).

**How do I reference the custom metadata type's ListView in my package.xml?**

What I've tried:

```
<types>
    <members>Conference_RSVP_Config__mdt.All_Conferences</members>
    <name>ListView</name>
</types>
```

The result:

```
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'Conference_RSVP_Config__mdt.All_Conferences' cannot
 be found
```

Comment: whats your API version ?

Comment: 40.0 for my package.xml. 41.0 for the Workbench, where I can't find the ListView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List view fetching for custom metadata types are bit tricky.

> If you retrieve a List View on a Custom Setting/Custom Metdata along with the Custom
>   Setting/Metadata object when using Metadata API in a single transaction, the
>   List View information is not retrieved.

You have to retrieve both separately.

Suppose:

**MetaData Object Name**: MyObject__mdt

**ListView Unique Name**: My_View

Then your listview package.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"> 
<types> 
<members>MyObject__mdt.My_View</members> 
<name>ListView</name> 
</types> 
<version>39.0</version> 
</Package>
```

It will retrieve Object file for you containing the Listview

Known Issue Link : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BCTQA2

Comment: Thanks for this, @Pranay Jaiswal.  The Known Issue you linked to solves my problem.  However, would you please update your response to emphasize the key here, which is that if you retrieve a List View on a Custom MDT **along with** the Custom MDT object when using Metadata API in a single transaction, the List View information is not retrieved. I had to **remove** the retrieve of the CustomObject iin order to get the list views to show up, until the Summer '18 release which apparently resolves the issue.

Comment: That was my first line , somehow got ommited :/ Edited finally.

Comment: You can still retrieve CustomObjects by using the build.xml and specifying a second package file and 2 `sf:retrieve` commands inside one target node. 

`<sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="test" unpackaged="test/package0.xml"/>`

`<sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="test" unpackaged="test/package.xml"/>`
-

Answer (score 1):

(Winter 23)

My testing shows that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
    <members>MyCustomMDT__mdt</members>
   </types>
   <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```

will:

- Retrieve listviews declared as `Visible to All` users
- Will not retrieve listviews as `Visible only to me`. And, [MDAPI doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm) says this is WAD `List views with the Visible only to me Restrict Visibility option aren’t accessible in Metadata API. Each of these list views is associated with a particular user.`